# ListBox touch scrolling performance

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, listbox

### My Problem

I have a problem with developing a touch friendly UI for an embedded device. 
Using the standard ListBox from WPF 4.0, which supports touch events and touch scrolling out of the box,  the touch scrolling performance is way worse than scrolling via pulling the scrollbar with a mouse.
Most notably, when starting a scroll flick, the scrolling stutters for a fraction of a second, but enough to feel bad and make flicks almost unusable (the gesture is complete when the stuttering stops, resulting in no, or minimal response).
As a reference I used touch scrolling in Windows Explorer, which has no problems and reacts smoothly.

Why is touch scrolling for the ListBox that much worse than both scrolling with the mouse, and touch scrolling in the explorer?

### My Test Code

```xml
<ListBox x:Name="listBox"
         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Brush}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Width="100"
                            Height="100"
                            Fill="{Binding}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Color}" FontSize="36" Margin="20"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>            
</ListBox>
```

The ItemsSource is set to an `IEnumerable<Brush>` containing all 141 brushes in System.Windows.Media.Brushes.

### What I tried

I've played around with some configuration options without avail. I tried

- `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing` both true and false
- Reducing the number of brushes to 20
- Explicitly settings the ItemsPanel to a VirtualizingStackPanel
- `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"`  (hard to jugde then, but I think the problem persists)

Since mouse scrolling is fine, I didn't really expect these to help any, but.. well.. I tried. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround I reimplemented the touch scrolling using the `TouchX` events. This works as smoothly as can be expected from the system its running on.

Comment: Can you provide some code on how you did this?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not, sorry. The code belongs to my employer. =/ On TouchDown, I start collecting all TouchMove events and change VerticalScrollOffset according to the distance moved. On TouchUp, I estimate the final velocity and continue to scroll in a running Timer, reducing the Velocity using normal friction rules.

Comment: I have implemented this and it does indeed improve performance.  Did you ever discover the root cause of why the touch scrolling is so abysmal?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"`?

Comment: I have now. I does not help, sadly. Virtualizaion is off due to `CanContentScroll=False` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

in Microsoft.Surface SDK, SurfaceListBox is a very nice control that supports all the touch event [Microsoft surface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh241326.aspx)